# AngularJS is not working in MVC PartialView

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have a Index.cshtml and I call a PartialView. I also use angularJS. My question is about...

My Index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="input"/>
        <p>{{input}}</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="callPv()">call partial</button>
    </div>
    <div id="divPv">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var callPv = function() {
        $("#divPv").load("Home/TestPV");    
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My PartialView

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="pv"/>
    <p>{{pv}}</p>
</div>
```

My angular.js

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);    
app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {   

});
```

If I call partial view by using **@Html.Partial("TestPV")**, angular is working in partial view but if I call partial by ajax, angular is not working in partial and seeing **{{pv}}**. I face this problem often. I'm new to angular. I appreciate your assistance. Thank you so much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an angular function on click then use onclick 
angular.element.scope.apply();
This will initiate ur scope function manually

angular.element('[ng-controller=testctrl]').scope().apply